# Matlab-REGEXP- Extracting data between apostophes

Tags: regex, matlab

```
<a href="matlab:matlab.internal.language.introspective.errorDocCallback('ABCD_ABCD_ABCD>pushbutton_select_Callback', 'C:\work\XYZZLIBRARY\matlab\ADCCC_IQ_TOOL\ABCD_ABCD_ABCD.m', 255)" style="font-weight:bold">ABCD_ABCD_ABCD>pushbutton_select_Callback</a> (<a href="matlab: opentoline('C:\work\XYZZLIBRARY\matlab\ADCCC_IQ_TOOL\ABCD_ABCD_ABCD.m',255,0)">line 255</a>
```

So I have the above data, need to collect data between 'XXXXX' ( single quotes) .

New to REGEXP using split string but unable to get the solution yet !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
expression = '''([^'']+)''';
matchStr = regexp(myStr,expression,'match');
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xL4tD3/7)

If you dont want to include `'` (quotes) in the match use `tokens` keyword):

```
expression = '''([^'']+)''';
matchStr = regexp(myStr,expression,'tokens');
```

**Edit:** For making the regexp stop after first match use `once` keyword:

```
matchStr = regexp(myStr,expression,'match','once');
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! I was able to separate the text, Also is there anyway that I can stop the search after just one search per line ?, ( A line may have multiple and repeated data within single quotes, and I just need the first)

Answer (score 0):

In order to match and capture any characters between two single quotes other than a single quote, you can either use

```
'([^']*)'
```

or more conveniently the ungreedy modifier:

```
'(.*?)'
```